# Determine Solution Regularity of $-\Delta u + u =f$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

We consider the following equations in the distribution sense, considering $u\in \mathscr{D}^{'}$ and the derivatives are also in the distribution sense.

**Question 1**:

In $\mathbb{R}^d$, given $f \in L^2$, and $$-\Delta u +u =f,$$ can we deduce $u \in H^2$?

What I am sure of:

1) if $u \in \mathscr{D}^{'}$, i.e. $u$ is a distribution, then $u \in H^{2}_{loc}$.

2) if $u \in \mathcal{S}^{'}$, i.e. $u$ is a tempered distribution, then after applying Fourier transform, we can get the result.

**Question 2**:

In $\mathbb{R}^d$, given $f \in L^1$, and $$-\Delta u +u =f,$$ (i.e. the only change is that now $f\in L^1$) can we produce a counterexample that solution $u \notin W^{2,1}$?

Comment: A general remark: you need to specify in what sense the function $u$ you are looking for is a solution to the problem, otherwise your questions are not meaningful.

Comment: @GaC Thanks. Specification has been added.

Answer (score 2):

Taking $u\in\mathcal D'$ is not strong enough, since $(-\Delta+1)\exp(\omega\cdot x)=0$ for any $\omega\in S^{d-1}$.  But taking $u\in\mathcal S'$ removes these exponentially growing solutions.

Comment: Thanks! This really makes sense. Can you give any idea to Question 2?

Comment: @JohannBruckner It's the same as Question 1, since if you choose $f=0\in L^1$, the exponential solves the equation but is not in $W^{2,1}$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't say it clearly. I meant after restricting u to tempered distributions can you give a counterexample as asked in Question 2. Thank you!

Comment: @JohannBruckner I can't think of one.  All I know is that $1-\Delta$ is injective in this case, so you just need to see if $(1-\Delta)^{-1}f$ is in $L^1$.  I can say that a counterexample will not happen for $d=1$, since then the inverse Fourier transform of $(1+|\xi|^2)^{-1}$ is in $L^1$, and Young's inequality applies.